# Load testing in an application using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-api, jmeter, load-testing

How to create load tests for an application that uses Firebase?
It is possible to create typical load tests using e.g. JMeter?

Using Firebase creates communication between the front-end side and the Firebase platform. When creating load tests, we must manually set many different parameters on these requests (e.g. token, different ids, etc.). The SDK containing the Google API is used to communicate with the platform. It has multiple methods that create multiple requests.  Can we handle them, know what parameters to set dynamically, what should they represent, where they come from and finally create load tests?